# Dynamically Creating multiple divs inside a single div after four child divs are created using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating dynamic div and image tags, there is a parent div and it contains multiple rows 
which is represented by row-fluid, row-fluid contains other two divs as shown in image, 
each row contains four of these images, but the problem is i have to create row-fluid initially,
but after that it will only be created after four images have been displayed in that div and 
appended to it, in that sequence only i have to create it, below is the code i am using, Please
my issue. Thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 0;

    $.each(description, function(key,value) {

    var s_image_path=value.s_img_path;


    var mainDiv = document.getElementById('parent');

    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.setAttribute('class','row-fluid'); 


    var album_img=document.createElement('img');
    album_img.setAttribute('class','img-responsive'); 


    var aTag = document.createElement('a');
    aTag.setAttribute('class','thumbnail t_clicked');

    var img_div_3 = document.createElement('div');
    img_div_3.setAttribute('class','col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb');

    var img_div_2 = document.createElement('div');
    img_div_2.setAttribute('class','span4');

    mainDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
    newDiv.appendChild(img_div_2); 
    img_div_2.appendChild(img_div_3);
    img_div_3.appendChild(aTag);
    aTag.appendChild(album_img);

    });
</script>
```

eg:

```
<div class="row-fluid">

        <div class="span4">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/gallery/photo111.jpg" alt="">
                </a>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="span4">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                 <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/gallery/photo10.jpg" alt="">
                 </a>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="span4">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/gallery/photo11.jpg" alt="">
                </a>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>



<div class="row-fluid">

            <div class="span4">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/gallery/photo111.jpg" alt=""/>
                    </a>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="span4">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                     <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/gallery/photo10.jpg" alt="">
                     </a>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="span4">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/gallery/photo11.jpg" alt="">
                    </a>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I created row-fluid div first time but was unable to create that div again after 4 image is displayed within it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are already using jQuery, so take advantage of it.  You can replace those verbose dom manipulation methods with more concise jQuery calls:

```
var mainDiv = $('#parent');

$.each(description, function(key,value) {
    var rowDiv = $('<div>').addClass('row-fluid').appendTo(mainDiv); 
    var img_div_2 = $('<div>').addClass('span4').appendTo(rowDiv);
    var img_div_3 = $('<div>').addClass('col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb').appendTo(img_div_2);
    var aTag = $('<a>').addClass('thumbnail t_clicked').appendTo(img_div_3);
    $('<img>').addClass('img-responsive').appendTo(aTag);
});
```

There, that's better.  Now, to only add the `row-fluid` div after there are four images, pull that variable out of the loop, and re-create the div as needed:

```
var mainDiv = $('#parent');
var rowDiv = $('<div>').addClass('row-fluid').appendTo(mainDiv);
$.each(description, function(key,value) {
    if (rowDiv.children().length >= 4) {
        rowDiv = $('<div>').addClass('row-fluid').appendTo(mainDiv);
    }
    var img_div_2 = $('<div>').addClass('span4').appendTo(rowDiv);
    var img_div_3 = $('<div>').addClass('col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb').appendTo(img_div_2);
    var aTag = $('<a>').addClass('thumbnail t_clicked').appendTo(img_div_3);
    $('<img>').addClass('img-responsive').appendTo(aTag);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.... but i'm still facing the same problem, the problem is row-fluid div is not created for individual row that though is created if i comment the if condition code, but when i run the same code with if condition only one time row-fluid div is created without any other div created inside. Please give some solution why this issue is coming.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you show me in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or a runnable code snippet?